# Javascript not executing?

Tags: javascript

I have this html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Bank page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./styles/main.css">
    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/config.js"></script>
    <script src="./scripts/bankoperations.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <div class="container">
            <div id="logoArea"></div>
            <div id="navArea">
                <ul id="nav">
                    <a href="./index.html"><li>Home</li></a>
                    <a href="./bank.html"><li>Bank</li></a>
                    <a href="./about.html"><li>About</li></a>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="mainArea">
        <div class="container page">
            <table id="operations">
                <caption>Bank operations with card</caption>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this js filling my table with content:

```
$(document)
    .ready(function () {
        // Send an AJAX request
        $.getJSON(window.appConfiguration.bankOperationSeviceUri)
            .done(function (data) {
                // On success, 'data' contains a list of products.
                $.each(data,
                    function (key, item) {
                        $('#operations tr:last')
                            .after('<tr><td>' +
                                item.OperationName +
                                '</td><td>' +
                                item.OperationDateTime +
                                '</td><td>' +
                                item.Amount +
                                '</td></tr>');
                    });
            });
    });
```

But when I execute this code - nothing happens. Though I can see table row created in debugger in Chrome, but nothing appends to table element on page. What can cause this error?

Comment: Why is it off-topic? Someone can explain?

Answer (score -1):

`$('#operations tr:last')` doesn't match any elements — your table has no table rows — so there is nothing to append after.

Try simply appending to the table instead.

```
$('#operations tbody:last').append(...)
```